# Layout and Layout-list centers differing

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, center, splash-screen

I want to impement a Splash Screen for my app following this tutorial: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

So I define the layout-list etc. and it seems to work perfect. The problem comes when I want to switch from the splash screen to a real activity which will first have the same graphics as the splash screen (the user does not have to notice it has changed from the splash screen to an activity). However, I define in both cases (in the splash screen xml code and in the activity's layout code) to have an image in the center as follows:

1- Splash screen

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/grey_dark"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_rounded"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

2.- Activity's layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_dark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_rounded"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Despite defining both to be in the center of the screen, they aren't actually in the same place as the center for the splash screen seems to be considered some pixels above from the ones for the layout.

Anybody knows why is it happening? Why does not place both of them in the real screen's center?

Thank you.